# replace value with other dataframe as reference

Tags: r

I am trying to replace column `a1` of dataframe `df1` by value `b1` of dataframe `df1`, if `a1` matches. Please help me achieve this using basic `R` functions

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = c("b2","c2","abc2"),b1 = c("bb2","cc2","d2"))
df2 <- data.frame(d1 = c("sale","sale2","sale3"),a1 = c("b2","c2","d2"))

> df2
     a1 b1
1  sale b2
2 sale2 c2
3 sale3 d2
```

Expected output:

```
     a1  b1
1  sale bb2
2 sale2 cc2
3 sale3  d2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I like to add the reference table to the original table. For example, (using `dplyr`) you might do something like:

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = "a1") %>% mutate(new_b1 = ifelse(!is.na(b1), b1, a1))
```

Which results in

```
    d1 a1   b1 new_b1
1  sale b2  bb2    bb2
2 sale2 c2  cc2    cc2
3 sale3 d2 <NA>     d2
```

In order to get your stated desired result, although it feels a bit weird to change the merging column but everything is possible, you might do something like:

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = "a1") %>% 
  mutate(b1 = ifelse(!is.na(b1), b1, a1)) %>% 
  select(-a1) %>% 
  rename(a1 = d1)
```

which results in

```
     a1  b1
1  sale bb2
2 sale2 cc2
3 sale3  d2
```

Answer (score 2):

One `base R` possibility could be:

```
pmax(df2$a1, df1$b1[match(df2$a1, df1$a1)], na.rm = TRUE)

[1] "bb2" "cc2" "d2"
```

It requires to import your data using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Or:

```
ifelse(is.na(matching), df2$a1, matching); matching <- df1$b1[match(df2$a1, df1$a1)]
```